# Newbie Python User Math

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner at this; I just started coding today and I'm having this problem.
The code kind of works except it won't add, subtract, divide, or anything else: it just says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`  or it just puts the number.  Can someone help me? Here is a example of the code:

```
a = input("Enter First Name:")
b = input("Enter Last Name:")
c = (" Welcome to the New World Order")
print ("Hey " + a + b+ c)
d = (": ")
num = input("Please enter a number "+a+b+d)
num1 = input("Please enter another number "+a+b+d)
num2 = num+num1
print ('is this your number umm ... ', (num2))
input ("Press<enter>")
```

Comment: `d = (": ")` – You do not need to put the string inside parentheses. Just `d = ": "` is enough :)

Comment: Your code will not produce a `TypeError` (regardless of whether you're using Python 2 or 3), so what part did you leave out?

Comment: The error message you mentioned said something about `-`. But there is no attempt to use `-` in the code you showed. Show the real code that actually causes the error. Also please learn to read error messages. They really are not that difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The input is always a "str" (string) type, you need to convert those to int or float to do math operations on them.

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number "+a+b+d))
```

Note that if the user enters something that is not a valid number, the entire program will crash, to handle that you must use **try**, **except**.

Comment: Thanks guys this was a big help ... LtWorf ur answer helped thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter First Name:")
lname = raw_input("Enter Last Name:")
c = (" Welcome to the New World Order")
print ("Hey " + fname + " " + lname + c)
d = (": ")

num  = raw_input("Please enter a number "+ fname + " " + lname +" " + d)
num1 = raw_input("Please enter another Number "+ fname + " " + lname +" " + d)

num2 = int(num) +  int(num1)

print '%s %s is these your numbers umm ... '% (num,num1)
print '%d is sum of  your numbers umm ... '% (num2)
raw_input ("Press<enter>")
```

> I think this is what you want to do.
>
> If you are complete newbie you should probably learn python first.
>
> Use this one [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)
>
> or For more concepts [Read Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns *strings* and those would be concatenated instead of summed unless you convert them to numbers first (and would throw a `TypeError` when trying to substract, multiply or divide them):

```
>>> "1" + "2"
'12'
>>> "1" - "2"
Traceback: <snip>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
>>> "1" * "2"
Traceback: <snip>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>> "1" * 2  # This is possible (but is still concatenation)!
'11'
>>> "1" / "2"
Traceback: <snip>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

You need to create integers from your values using `int()`:

```
num2 = int(num) + int(num1)
```

This will throw a `ValueError` if either `num` or `num1` does not contain anything that can be interpreted as an integer, so you may want to catch that:

```
try:
    num2 = int(num) + int(num1)
    print ('is this your number umm ... ', num2)
except ValueError:
    print('You really should enter numbers!')
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Heh, the OP tried subtracting indeed. Corrected.